# Creating lists inside a list in Python

Tags: python, list

```
values = ['random word1', 20, 'random word2', 54…]
```

The list has a string then a value and again a string then afterwards a value. The amount of strings followed by values is random. The words are random and the values are random as well

I want to convert the list to something like this:

```
values = [['random word1', 20], ['random word2', 54]…]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
values = ['random word1', 20, 'random word2', 54]
values = [values[i:i+2] for i in range(0,len(values),2)]
print(values)
```

Comment: I have tried this method as well it works. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```py
values = ['random word1', 20, 'random word2', 54]
print([list(x) for x in zip(values[::2], values[1::2])])
```

Comment: I have tried this method as well it works. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with `zip` and list slicing.

```
list(map(list,zip(values[::2], values[1::2])))
# [['random word1', 20], ['random word2', 54]]
```

Comment: `list(map(list,zip( ...` I suppose it's too much for the beginning beginner to understand what will be going on without a page or two of explanations ...

Comment: I have tried this method as well it works. I will choose this one as best because there is no for loop involved. I guess if the list had thousands of strings and values this would run faster than the other answers correct?

Comment: @ETHERC20, I think this method **does** for loops. Functions like [`map()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) and [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) create an iterator, so you need to do a for loop if you want to process all the elements, this is what [`list()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-list) function does.

Comment: @Mayo in this case what would you suggest? If the list had tens of thousands of strings and values it will run slow correct? How can I make it better?

Answer (score -2):

```
b = [[values[i], values[i+1]] for i in range(len(values)) if i%2==0]
```

Comment: First think, than write code and finally test the code before posting anything here on stackoverflow.

Comment: It's actually what' i've done, but with a very specific (and wrong) test case. There is no need to be rude.